# how to edit the external model data form view in Kendo Grid MVC

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a problem figuring out how to implement the Multiple model edit in **Kendo Grid MVC** Edit Popup?

I have a Kendo grid whereas the editable options are defined as:

```
Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("TapView").Window(w => w.Width(900)).Window(o => o.Height(650)));
```

In Tapview I loaded the Multiple View.

```
 tabstrip.Add().Text("Child")
            .Selected(true)
            .Content(@<text>
              @Html.Action("pagename1", "controller");
            </text>);
    tabstrip.Add().Text("title").LoadContentFrom("pagename2");
    tabstrip.Add().Text("title").LoadContentFrom("pagename3");
```

If i edit the Grid details i showed the corresponding data related to the grid.but when i edit the 2nd tapstrip content i cant get the model from view an it became null.
How to get the edited model from gridpopup?

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ChildPopup_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Model1 obj, Model2 obj2)
    {

    obj2 is null here 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on serilizable issue.
I added DataContract to the class and add the DataMember to the class with in class.
Now it working perfect.